# Get website console log message through objective c

Tags: objective-c, console.log

Using ObjectiveC I had developed the browser like this

```
- (void)setupWebView {
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
self.webView.UIDelegate = self;
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;
self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
[self.baseView addSubview: self.webView];
[self setupWKWebViewConstain: self.webView];

}

- (void)setURL:(NSString *)requestURLString {
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: requestURLString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url
                                              cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval: 5];
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
}

#pragma mark - WKScriptMessageHandler Methods
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
NSLog(@"log: %@", message.name);
}
```

In my website I had given

console.log("Hello world!");

This console value will keep changing, I want to get those values through ObjectiveC, I tried didReceiveScriptMessage but it is not working.

Is there any other way to get console.log values through Objective C

Comment: You can connect safari's debugger to your's webview to see console logs and do other web things

Comment: Is there any sample code available to get the console log.